# Woo REST API output sale price wrong

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce

I'm in big trouble, because on live site I just discovered that our API put strange output and due to that can not sync products with our ERP and CRM. I think the problem is in this piece of code but I can not figure out how to keep it because it works on frotnend but exclude it from API Json output?

```
//PROCENT SPARET PÅ SIMPLE PRODUCT
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
// Getting the clean numeric prices (without html and currency)
$_reg_price = floatval( strip_tags($regular_price) );
$_sale_price = floatval( strip_tags($sale_price) );

// Percentage calculation and text
$percentage = round( ( $_reg_price - $_sale_price ) / $_reg_price * 100 ).'%';
$percentage_txt = '(' . __('-', 'woocommerce' ) . $percentage . ')';

$formatted_regular_price = is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price;
$formatted_sale_price    = is_numeric( $sale_price )    ? wc_price( $sale_price )    : $sale_price;

echo '<del>' . $formatted_regular_price . '</del> <ins>' . $formatted_sale_price ."<span class='percentage_save'>". $percentage_txt . "</span>".'</ins>';
}
```

And problem in output is visible here [image: JSON Output]

Does anybody have idea how to quickly fix that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* you can user this hook function for above issue */

  add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_price_func', 10, 2 );

  function custom_price_func( $price, $product){
     /* write your stuff here */
     return $price;
  }
```